# Not able to call 2 functions in CIL

Tags: c#, cil

I've started learning CIL today and have been using multiple tutorials to gain a basic understanding.

Currently I have 2 functions, 1 function adds 10 to the integer given as an argument and prints the answer. The second function takes 2 integers, add 5 to both of them and than multiplies the answers. Than it gets returned.

Both the functions work when only 1 of them is called, but when both are called I get the following error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.
>
> at Bewerkingen.Program.Main(String[] args)

I do not know how to make the 2 functions work when called after each other. This is my code:

```
.assembly extern mscorlib {} 
.assembly Bewerkingen {} 
.module Bewerkingen.exe

.class public Functions
extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
 .method public specialname void .ctor()
 {
  ret
 }
 .method public void Add(int32)
 {
  ldarg.1
  ldc.i4 10
  add
  call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
  ret
 }
 .method public int32 add5mul(int32,int32)
 {
  ldarg.1
  ldc.i4 5
  add
  ldarg.2
  ldc.i4 5
  add
  mul
  ret
 }
}

.class Bewerkingen.Program
extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
 .method static void Main(string[] args)
 cil managed
 {
  .entrypoint
  newobj instance void Functions::.ctor()
  ldc.i4 3
  call instance void Functions::Add(int32)
  ldc.i4 5
  ldc.i4 3
  call instance int32 Functions::add5mul(int32,int32)
  call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
  ret
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a slight problem, in that your `.ctor` needs to call the base object's ctor (`ldarg.0`, `call instance void [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Object::.ctor()`, `ref`). Both for Program and for Functions

The main problem however is that you try and call `add5mul` on... nothing. There's no `Functions` object on the stack to call it on.

```
// Push Functions instance onto stack
// Stack: [functions]
  newobj instance void Functions::.ctor()

// Push 3 onto stack
// Stack: [3, functions]
  ldc.i4 3

// Pop 3 and functions off the stack
// Stack: []
  call instance void Functions::Add(int32)

// Push 5 and 3 onto stack
// Stack: [3, 5]
  ldc.i4 5
  ldc.i4 3

// Pop 5, 3, and... nothing. We're missing the Functions instance to call it on.
  call instance int32 Functions::add5mul(int32,int32)
```

You can fix this by duplicating the Functions instance before you consume it for the first time:

```
  newobj instance void Functions::.ctor()
  dup                                                     <-- Here
  ldc.i4 3
  call instance void Functions::Add(int32)
  ldc.i4 5
  ldc.i4 3
  call instance int32 Functions::add5mul(int32,int32)
  call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
  ret
```

You can also store that Functions instance in a local slot:

```
.method static void Main(string[] args)
 cil managed
 {
  .locals init (
    [0] class Functions
  )
  .entrypoint
  newobj instance void Functions::.ctor()
  stloc.0
  ldloc.0
  ldc.i4 3
  call instance void Functions::Add(int32)
  ldloc.0
  ldc.i4 5
  ldc.i4 3
  call instance int32 Functions::add5mul(int32,int32)
  call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
  ret
 }
```

---

[SharpLab.io](https://sharplab.io) is a great resource for learning IL. [Here's your code, translated to C# then decompiled into IL](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBLANgHwAEAmARgFgAoQgZgAISHSB2Kgbyrq4eOM+46VuwugDcAhlDoAzAK4A7MBmwR5AZzoBeOvJgB3BgFZlqtQAoAlAG5+ImQqUr1AOgCCAE3dma12yMKkAJxmcoomLuKehgC2srhmhmh0Pr5C3AC+VJmUVLQ8RuFq7H55hCh0Hl7Y8hh04hZ+gnbcAcHidADUdKQADNbcftnCedW1ke4xcWajdUkzwA1pXE3NDMx0Zu1dhhZ0AFQbwJ10O1YDS3TZ6UA=).

Answer (score 1):

Your first function call consumes the object references needed to call a non static function. Save the object reference after the `newobj` operation to a local variable and load that reference for each function call.

From the msdn:

> Calls to an instance (or virtual) method must push that instance reference before any of the user-visible arguments. The instance reference must not be a null reference. The signature carried in the metadata does not contain an entry in the parameter list for the this pointer; instead, it uses a bit to indicate whether the method requires passing the this pointer.
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.call?view=netframework-4.8